# Evaluation $(n+1)th$ derivative of $\ln(1-x^2)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

The function $\ln(1-x^2)$ is approximated about $x=0$ by an *n*th degree Taylor's Polynomial. Find *n* such that

$|Error|<0.1$ on $0\leq x\leq0.5$.

*My Try*: So I know to evaluate the remainder term of the Taylor polynomial, I can use the following expression

> $$R_n (x)=\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot f^{n+1}(\xi)$$

My doubt is, how do I find the $(n+1)th$ derivative of $\ln(1-x^2) $? I don't see any pattern in its smaller derivatives. How do I evaluate the same?

Comment: $\ln(1-x^2)=\ln(1+x)+\ln(1-x)$, but that isn't how I'd work out the Taylor polynomial...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What do you mean ?

Comment: I'd work out the Taylor polynomial of $\ln(1-y)$ and then set $y=x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I would write $$\ln(1-x^2)=\ln(1-x)+\ln(1+x)$$

Answer (score 0):

you know the expansion of
$$\ln(1-x) = - x - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4 }- \cdots$$

replace $x$ with $x^2$
$$\ln(1-x^2) = - x^2 - \frac{x^4}{2} - \frac{x^6}{3} - \frac{x^8}{4 }- \cdots$$

nth term is $$a_n=-\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\hspace{10pt}n\ge 1$$

you want  $$\left|-\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n+1}\right| \le 0.1 \hspace{10pt}, 0\le x\le 0.5$$

Comment: What is the use of the nth term for me ?

Comment: how would you write the $R_n(x)$ then

Comment: Bounding the truncation of a series by the next term works *in general* only for an alternating series whose terms decrease in magnitude.

Comment: ok then for this series what do we do ?